# Is it safe to uninstall samba if I don't use it?

Tags: uninstall, samba

I didn't manually install samba on my Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop. Neither do I use it for anything. So is it safe to remove it?

If I remove it the following packages will be removed with it, which also I did not install:

```
samba-common samba-common-bin smbclient
```

It should have come already installed with Ubuntu, right?

Note: The reason for removing the package is because I get these at boot-up, for which  could not find a solution on google:

```
[    7.934204] nfc: nfc_init: NFC Core ver 0.1
[    8.159216] init: Failed to spawn smbd main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
[    8.161379] init: Failed to spawn samba-ad-dc main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
[   11.597139] init: winbind main process (1789) terminated with status 127
[   11.597162] init: winbind main process ended, respawning
[   11.628060] init: winbind main process (1793) terminated with status 127
[   11.628080] init: winbind main process ended, respawning
[   11.669705] init: Failed to spawn nmbd main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
[   11.671606] init: winbind main process (1805) terminated with status 127
[   11.671628] init: winbind main process ended, respawning
[   11.709035] init: winbind main process (1828) terminated with status 127
[   11.709059] init: winbind main process ended, respawning
[   11.725831] init: winbind main process (1842) terminated with status 127
[   11.725849] init: winbind main process ended, respawning
[   11.738188] init: winbind main process (1848) terminated with status 127
[   11.738204] init: winbind main process ended, respawning
[   11.749750] init: winbind main process (1851) terminated with status 127
[   11.749770] init: winbind main process ended, respawning
[   11.763776] init: winbind main process (1854) terminated with status 127
[   11.763791] init: winbind main process ended, respawning
[   11.779336] init: winbind main process (1857) terminated with status 127
[   11.779353] init: winbind main process ended, respawning
[   11.795904] init: winbind main process (1860) terminated with status 127
[   11.795919] init: winbind main process ended, respawning
[   11.811539] init: winbind main process (1863) terminated with status 127
[   11.811557] init: winbind respawning too fast, stopped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [winbindd](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/winbindd.8.html) — Name Service Switch daemon for resolving names from NT
>   servers
>
> winbindd is a daemon that provides a number of services to the Name
>   Service Switch capability found in most modern C libraries, to
>   arbitrary applications via PAM and ntlm_auth and to Samba itself.

And yes it's safe to remove samba:

```
sudo apt-get remove samba
```

to remove samba4:

```
sudo apt-get remove samba4
```

Comment: For the record, will removing samba solve the dmesg messages?